# PyQt5. QPixmap Масштабирование изображения

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, изображения, qpixmap

Вставленное изображение `QPixmap` меняет расстояние между строками в форме и не масштабируется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправить расстояние между строк можно с помощью метода `setSizePolicy` и `Qsize.Policy`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но масштабирование изображения не работает:

```
self.img_label = QLabel()
img_pixmap = QPixmap("config/img/internet.png")
img_pixmap.scaled(50, 50, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.img_label.setPixmap(img_pixmap)
self.img_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
```

также пробовал использовать методы `img_pixmap.scaledToWidth(50)` и `img_pixmap.scaledToHeight(50)` - безуспешно, метод `QLabel().setScaledContents(True)` меняет геометрию изображения растягивая ее по горизонтали, оригинальное изображение имеет размер 200х200 px. Подскажите в чем проблема?

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainAppInterface(QMainWindow):

    MAIN_APP_HEIGHT = 400
    MAIN_APP_WIDTH = 700

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.setMinimumHeight(self.MAIN_APP_HEIGHT)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.MAIN_APP_WIDTH)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test Forms")

        group_box = QGroupBox("Test Forms")

        detail_box = DetailBox()

        v_spacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        g_layout = QGridLayout()
        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("BLA BLA BLA"), 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(detail_box, 2, 1)
        g_layout.addItem(v_spacer, 3, 1)

        group_box.setLayout(g_layout)

        h_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        h_layout.addWidget(group_box)


class DetailBox(QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self, detail_dict: dict = None, parent=None):

        super(DetailBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setTitle("Detail")

        self.detail_dict = detail_dict

        self.name_line = QLineEdit()
        self.name_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.description_line = QLineEdit()
        self.description_line.setReadOnly(True)

        self.img_label = QLabel()
        img_pixmap = QPixmap("config/img/internet.png")
        img_pixmap.scaled(50, 50, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.img_label.setPixmap(img_pixmap)
        self.img_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)

        self.model_line = QLineEdit()
        self.model_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.ip_address_line = QLineEdit()
        self.ip_address_line.setReadOnly(True)

        self.login_datetime_line = QLineEdit()
        self.login_datetime_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.login_duration_line = QLineEdit()
        self.login_datetime_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.logout_datetime_line = QLineEdit()
        self.logout_datetime_line.setReadOnly(True)

        self.p_name_line = QLineEdit()
        self.p_name_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.p_description_line = QLineEdit()
        self.p_description_line.setReadOnly(True)

        self.user_id_line = QLineEdit()
        self.user_id_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.user_display_name_line = QLineEdit()
        self.user_display_name_line.setReadOnly(True)

        g_layout = QGridLayout(self)

        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Name"), 1, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.name_line, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Description"), 2, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.description_line, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Login Date Time"), 3, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.login_datetime_line, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Login Duration"), 4, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.login_duration_line, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Logout Date Time"), 5, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.logout_datetime_line, 5, 2, 1, 1)

        g_layout.addWidget(self.img_label, 1, 3, 5, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Profile Name / Description"), 6, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.p_name_line, 6, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.p_description_line, 6, 3, 1, 1)

        g_layout.addWidget(QLabel("UserId / DisplayName"), 7, 1, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.user_id_line, 7, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.user_display_name_line, 7, 3, 1, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ex = MainAppInterface()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [scaled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) не меняет текущее изображение, а возвращает новое

Попробуйте так:

```
img_pixmap = img_pixmap.scaled(50, 50, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Comment: cпасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Luarvick, пожалуйста :)